# Removing underline from specific anchor tag

Tags: css

Why does the following anchor tag has text underlined?

```css
.pagerLink {
  background-color: #E4F5F8;
  border: 1px solid #C0DEED;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="pagerLink" href="#">test</a>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Probably because another style block has better [precedence](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-inheritance-cascade/) than your `pagerLink` class. Try:

```
.pagerLink {
    background-color: #E4F5F8;
    border: 1px solid #C0DEED; 
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: that worked. Is it because I am using a:link
{
    color: #0084B4;
    text-decoration: underline; 
} ? Is that the reason it's retaining underline?

Comment: @progtick, yes, especially if that style comes *after* `.pagerLink` in your stylesheet.

Comment: it came before it, but i guess it still persisted

Comment: @progtick, that might even depend on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

use text-decoration:none for a in your styles

Ex:

```
<head>  
 <style>

  .pagerLink
   {
     background-color: #E4F5F8;
     border:1px solid #C0DEED; 
   }
  .pagerLink a
  {
    text-decoration:none !important;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pagerLink">
    <a href="somepage.aspx">test</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can use firebug(a firefox plugin) to findout which style is being used for the element now and whether its being overwritten by some other style definition

http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: it didn't work, but I am not using css in <head> just so you know

Comment: @progtick , it is inheriting from somewhere , you can use the firebug from which class it is inherting tat.

Answer (score 1):

I cant yet leave comments and I respect this is an old question but be extremely careful when using !important in your declarations:

`text-decoration: none !important;`

You'll probably get away with it in smaller projects but with any non-trivial project that involves collaboration from multiple sources this sort of thing can be incredibly annoying when it over-rides a property I need to set further down the line.  Not only do I have to change this to make my fix stick but I also have to check that changing it does not break anything else, which it probably will.

Better is to refactor your declaration or restructure your code so that you dont need to use `!important` and **only** fall back to `!important` when you cant.

Answer (score 0):

To remove underline you need to follow following style code snippet.

```
.pagerLink{
  background-color: #E4F5F8;
  border:1px solid #C0DEED; 
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```